# Vue js : Call a child method from the parent component

Tags: javascript, animation, methods, vue.js

I tried to make communicate to components with vuejs and vuex :

1. First component is a `menu`
2. Second component, inside the first, is an `hamburgerButton`.

In this very current case, when I click the `hamburgerButton`, this one is animated and the menu too. With this code, after the button click, the `menu` is animated with vueTransition and the `hamburgerButton` too. Note that i use vuex to manage a `menuIsOpen` state.

My problem is when i click an item of the menu, I would like fired the `hamburgerButton` animation.

`hamburgerButton`animation method, call `animButtonHandler()`, is encapsulated in a `@click` event. Actually i understand why it doesn't work right know, but I don't perceive how to handle this method to the click of a Parent element (item of the menu). So my question is, how can I access a method to a child component from a parent component ? Or is there an another workaround methodology to achieve this ?

parent component - menu.vue :

```
<template>
    <div class="menu">
        <!-- import hamburgerButton component -->
        <hamburger-button></hamburger-button>
        <transition v-on:enter="enterMenuHandler" v-on:leave="leaveMenuHandler">
            <div class="menu_wrapper" v-if="this.$store.state.menuIsOpen">
                <ul class="menu_items">
                    <li class="menu_item" @click="$store.commit('toggleMenu')">
                        <router-link class="menu_link" to="/">home</router-link>
                        <router-link class="menu_link" to="/contact">contact</router-link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </transition>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import hamburgerButton from "hamburgerButton.vue";

export default {
    components: {
        'hamburger-button': hamburgerButton,
    },
    methods: {
        enterMenuHandler(el, done){
            TweenLite.fromTo(el, 0.5, {
                opacity: '0',
            },{
                opacity: '1',
                onComplete: done
            });
        },
        leaveMenuHandler(el, done){
            TweenLite.to(el, 0.5, {
                opacity: '0',
                onComplete: done
            });
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

child component : hamburgerButton.vue :

```
<template>
    <div class="hamburgerButton" @click="animButtonHandler()">
        <div class="hamburgerButton_inner" ref="hamburgerButtonInner">
            <i class="hamburgerButton_icon></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        animButtonHandler (){
            // toggle the state of menu if button clicked
            this.$store.commit('toggleMenu');
            const isOpen = this.$store.state.menuIsOpen === true;
            // anim the button
            TweenLite.to(this.$refs.hamburgerButtonInner, 0.5, {
                rotation: isOpen ? "43deg" : '0',
            });
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

store.js (imported in the main.js) :

```
let store = new Vuex.Store({
    state : {
            menuIsOpen : false,
    },
    mutations: {
        toggleMenu(state) {
            state.menuIsOpen = !state.menuIsOpen
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: hmm i guess best case would we event bus , checkout this link https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/ you can emit event from the parent component and you can listen in child component, when you trigger event child will execute your animation method. if you need  answer with example please let me know

Comment: @HardikSatasiya Thanks ! Yes it an example with my case would be really appreciated. I check the documentation

Comment: For animation I would recommand to use the build in `<transition>` that ships with Vue. Pass the `name` attribute and hook on to that. It will generate certain classes with the "name" value as the prefix.
In the CSS you specify your animations/transitions and how they should act.

Comment: i am not sure but i can make small bsaic example of it not using your code but simple and small , give me 2 min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added basic Example of event bus. you can now compare it with and do changes like wise.

if find any difficulties please comment.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <h2>event bus</h2>    
    <button @click="callChildAnimateMethod"> Button On Parent Call Child </button>     
    <childcmp><childcmp />
  </div>
  <script>  
  var EventBus = new Vue();
  
  Vue.component('childcmp', {
    template: `<div>child demo - {{ message }}</div>`,
    data: function() {
      return {
        message: 'hello'
      }
    },
    mounted: function() {
      // listen for event
      EventBus.$on('animate', this.animButtonHandler);
    },
    destroyed: function(){
      // remove listener
      EventBus.$off('animate', this.animButtonHandler);
      
    },
    methods: {
      animButtonHandler: function() {
        console.log('this is child method');
        this.message = 'I am changed.'
      }
    }
  });

   new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: function() {
        return {
          
        }
      },
      methods: {
        callChildAnimateMethod: function() {          
          EventBus.$emit('animate');
        }
      }

    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Update

---

you need to define **EventBus**

> eventbus.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
const EventBus = new Vue();
export default EventBus;
```

> parent component - menu.vue

```
import EventBus from './eventbus.js'
... your code
```

> child component : hamburgerButton.vue :

```
import EventBus from './eventbus.js'
... your code
```

now EventBus will be available to your code.

Comment: It's work in your example as expected in my case. Thanks ! However I tried to reproduce your example and I got an error `"TypeError: EventBus.$on is not a function"` on the `mounted` hook. Any Idea ?

Comment: my bad, I found why. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Since you wanted to know how to imtegrate event bus with your code, here it is:

Create an event bus which is just an empty vue instance

Add it in you main.js file or outsource it in a spererate file;

**main.js**

```
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

**menu.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="menu">
        <!-- import hamburgerButton component -->
        <hamburger-button></hamburger-button>
        <transition v-on:enter="enterMenuHandler" v-on:leave="leaveMenuHandler">
            <div class="menu_wrapper" v-if="this.$store.state.menuIsOpen">
                <ul class="menu_items">
                    <li class="menu_item" @click="toggleMenu">
                        <router-link class="menu_link" to="/">home</router-link>
                        <router-link class="menu_link" to="/contact">contact</router-link>
                    </li>
                </ul>w
            </div>
        </transition>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import hamburgerButton from "hamburgerButton.vue";
import {EventBus} from './path/to/main.js' //or a path to file where you exported your EventBus

export default {
    components: {
        'hamburger-button': hamburgerButton,
    },
    methods: {
        toggleMenu(){
            this.$store.commit('toggleMenu');
            EventBus.$emit('animate-hamburger-btn');
        },
        enterMenuHandler(el, done){
            TweenLite.fromTo(el, 0.5, {
                opacity: '0',
            },{
                opacity: '1',
                onComplete: done
            });
        },
        leaveMenuHandler(el, done){
            TweenLite.to(el, 0.5, {
                opacity: '0',
                onComplete: done
            });
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

set up a event listener on the event bus in the created hook and perform the animation on every `animate-hamburger-btn` event

**hamburgerButton.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="hamburgerButton" @click="animButtonHandler()">
        <div class="hamburgerButton_inner" ref="hamburgerButtonInner">
            <i class="hamburgerButton_icon></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import {EventBus} from './path/to/main.js' //or a path to file where you exported your EventBus
export default {
    created(){
        EventBus.$on('animate-hamburger-btn', () => {
            this.animateBtn();
        });
    }.
    methods: {
        animButtonHandler (){
            // toggle the state of menu if button clicked
            this.$store.commit('toggleMenu');
            this.animateBtn();
        },
        animateBtn(){
            const isOpen = this.$store.state.menuIsOpen === true;
            // anim the button
            TweenLite.to(this.$refs.hamburgerButtonInner, 0.5, {
                rotation: isOpen ? "43deg" : '0',
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're right in my case I need to declare a globale bus event and this is working, thanks. But what about best practices ? Do I use a new global busEven each time I need to to emit even from other component ?

Comment: @BrownBe Nope you can use the same event bus, since you are using vuex, try to manage your logic using vuex